# Adding a new column based on other columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, keyerror

I have a large dataframe. Let me write a sample dataframe for let you understand my question.

```
A      B      C     
car    red    15
car    blue   20
car    grey   14
bike   red    6
bike   blue   8
phone  red    9
phone  blue   11
phone  grey   10
```

Let's say column C show the price. I want to add a column called "D". This columns will answer that "Is read car expensive than mean price of all cars?". And the same question for other A values. My question is basicly like that. I want to see this:

```
A      B      C    D    
car    red    15   cheap
car    blue   20   expensive
car    grey   14   cheap
bike   red    6    cheap
bike   blue   8    expensive
phone  red    9    cheap
phone  blue   11   expensive
phone  grey   10   cheap
```

I write too many way to do this task. Finally I thought that this code will solve my problem but it didn't. I tried the same thing with While loop but I am keep getting Key Error 0. What should I do? Here is the code I tried:

```
df["D"] = "cheap"
A.values = df.A.unique()
for b in A.values:
    for i in range(len(df.loc[data.A== b])):
        if df.loc[df.A== b, "C"][i] >= df.loc[df.A== b, "C"].mean():
            df.loc[df.A== b, "D"][i] = "expensive"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `transform` with `mean`, then do `np.where`

```
s = df.groupby('A').C.transform('mean')
df['D'] = np.where(df.C>s, 'expensive', 'cheap')
df
Out[158]: 
       A     B   C          D
0    car   red  15      cheap
1    car  blue  20  expensive
2    car  grey  14      cheap
3   bike   red   6      cheap
4   bike  blue   8  expensive
5  phone   red   9      cheap
6  phone  blue  11  expensive
7  phone  grey  10      cheap
```

Comment: Hey BEN_YO, this really solved my problem. I have another question if you don't mind. How can I do the same thing with %95 confidence interval instead of mean price? You used transform.("mean") in your code, is there a similar thing for values which are out of the confidence interval?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['D']=np.where(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x['C'].mean()>=x['C'])),'cheap','expensive')


     A     B   C          D
0    car   red  15      cheap
1    car  blue  20  expensive
2    car  grey  14      cheap
3   bike   red   6  expensive
4   bike  blue   8      cheap
5  phone   red   9      cheap
6  phone  blue  11  expensive
7  phone  grey  10      cheap
```

**How it works**

```
np.where(condition, if met answer, not met answer)


#Apply boolean select to get condition. In this statement we seek to return true if mean is greater than price

condition= df[['A', 'B', 'C']].groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x['C'].mean()>=x['C']))


if met answer= 'cheap'

not me t answer='expensive'
```